# Nested Scopes and Lambdas

Tags: python, lambda, nested

```
def funct():
    x = 4
    action = (lambda n: x ** n)
    return action

x = funct()
print(x(2)) # prints 16
```

... I don't quite understand why 2 is assigned to n automatically?

Comment: [beginner] and [lambda].  Consider that lambdas aren't for beginners and skip over them.  Ignore them.  You don't need them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`n` is the argument of the anonymous function returned by `funct`.  An exactly equivalent defintion of `funct` is

```
def funct():
    x = 4
    def action(n):
        return x ** n
    return action
```

Does this form make any more sense?

Answer (score 3):

It's not assigned "automatically": it's assigned very explicitly and **non**-automatically by your passing it as the actual argument corresponding to the `n` parameter.  That complicated way to set `x` is almost identical (net of `x.__name__` and other minor introspective details) to `def x(n): return 4**n`.