# How to call a function, it define in another function in python?

Tags: python

```
def out():
   var1 = "abc"
   print(var1)

   def inner():
      var2 = "def"
```

I want to call only "Inner" function... the final output should print only var2 not var1...

Thank you in advance

Comment: You'll have to move `inner()` and add a `print` call for `var2`. This is unrelated to django and tkinter btw.

Comment: Why dont you have just two different functions? is it some requirement in your project?

Comment: How can you want `var2` to be printed when you have no `print(var2)`? How do you want to call the function if you don't even return it in any way? Please, clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to run some part of the function 'out' you could use parameters.

```
def out(choice=True):
  if choice :
    var1 = "abc"
    print(var1)
 else :
    def inner():
       var2 = "def"
       print(var2)
    inner()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to call `inner` from outside the `out` function, since `inner` is only defined inside `out`, unless you create a reference to `inner` from outside the `out` function. In addition, `inner` is not outputting anything since it does not have a print statement.

To combat this, you have two options:

- Place `inner` in a broader scope (i.e. outside `out`) and add to it a `print(var1)` statement.
- If it is *required* to have the `inner` function be inside `out` then just return `inner` as a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) from `out`, with the print statement also inside `inner`; or just call it from inside `out`. This has a side-effect of also executing whatever statements are inside `out` up to returning the closure.

Comment: "You will not be able to call inner from outside the out function" <- Well *technically* it is possible to force the outer function to create a reference to the inner function in `globals()` on its first call. It's just not something you ever *want* to do.

Answer (score 0):

The method your trying is called as nested functions:

You can chek this answer for information about [nested function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2006017/7640269).

Some other information about [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))

**Another method is,**

```
def fun1():
    x = 11
    def fun2(a=a):
        print x
    fun2()

fun1()
```

**Output:**

```
prints 11
```

**Example 2:**

```
def f1(x):
    def add(y):
        return x + y
    return add

res = f1(5)
print(res(10))  # prints 15
```

Comment: Your first example is wrong. It gives an error saying a is undefined. Also, a colon is needed at the end of 'def fun2(a=a)'.

Comment: I missed the colon didnt notice that.. Would you provide the logs of undefined, I explained here the usage of inner functions in python.