# How can a variable to a function have parameters?

Tags: python

Running the code below prints `hellohello hellohellohello`
However, I never specified a parameter to either `twice` variable or `thrice` variable. 
Also, I never assigned `'hello'` to `word1`. 
How does it return the answer then? How can `twice` or `thrice` take in a parameter and equate it to `word1`?

```
def echo(n):
    """Return the inner_echo function."""

    def inner_echo(word1):
        """Concatenate n copies of word1."""
        echo_word = word1 * n
        return echo_word

    return inner_echo

twice = echo(2)
thrice = echo(3)

print(twice('hello'), thrice('hello'))
```

Comment: *"I never specified a parameter to either twice variable or thrice variable"* - yes you did. *"I never assigned hello to word1"* - yes you did. Key words: "higher order functions".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't python nested functions called closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/why-arent-python-nested-functions-called-closures)

Comment: `echo` returns `inner_echo` which is a function that accepts an argument. You are calling `echo` and assign its return value to `twice` and `thrice`. Thus `twice` and `thrice` are functions that accept an argument.

Comment: I understand that I assigned parameters to twice and thrice. But how can those parameters be then equated to word1. I don't get it still

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12423750/2823755

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005956/how-do-nested-functions-work-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Look at your last line of code, `print(twice('hello'), thrice('hello'))`. When you declared `twice` and `thrice` as your functions (`twice = echo(2)
thrice = echo(3)`), you are actually specifying `word1` as `hello`.

Comment: word1 is the parameter for inner_echo(). How can parameters for twice or thrice be equated to parameters for inner_echo()? I'm still not able to understand

Comment: So what you did is you placed the inner_echo() function inside of echo(n). Then you did twice = echo(n). Which means when you call twice you are actually calling echo(n).

Comment: I understand when I call twice I call echo(n). When echo(n) is called it in turn calls inner_echo(word1). My confusion is where/how is it specified that word1 is equal  to 'hello'

Comment: Inside echo(n) is inner_word(word1), When you write twice = echo(2). You have specified that parameter. So now when you call twice('hello'), you are actually calling twice(word1). You have put it inside your echo.